# How do I set my PHP executable path for PHP development in Visual Studio Code in WSL?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tried every answer I have seen in Stack Overflow and Github issues and still can not get my PHP executable to work with VSCode. I have attached a screenshot displaying my settings.json for VSCode. I will also attach a screenshot of the location of the php file. I have no idea how to fix this error. Please, I need some assistance. I have been trying at this for the last two hours. I believe it has something to do with the WSL Ubuntu wrapper in VSCode, but I'm not sure. The way I got the paths for the executables is using the command
`whereis php` in the ubuntu terminal

I have also tried "C:/php/php.exe"
And I even tried combinations using double forward slashes or backwards slashes. (These are all solutions I found in  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/251 that worked for other devs).

[image: setting.json]
[image: file location]

Comment: Hi guy! Also searching the best way for this. Finding it I come back here.